# Resteasy multipart/form-data encoding using pojo

Tags: resteasy, multipartform-data

I am having trouble with resteasy and multipart forms and I was hoping someone might have the same problem or would otherwise be able to help me.

My goal is to upload a file and some parameters at the same time. I tried this using the @MultipartForm annotated to a POJO-Form:

```
@PUT
@Path("/userdebug1/{userId}")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public String updateUserDebug1( @MultipartForm UserRequestForm request )
{
    return request.getName();
}
```

With UserRequestForm form being:

```
public class UserRequestForm 
{
    @FormParam("name")
    String name;

    @FormParam("blob")
    @PartType("application/octet-stream")
    byte[] image;

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String n) 
    {
        this.name =n;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() 
    {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) 
    {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

This all works well, except for the fact that **the character encoding is broken**. If I use an umlaut it's not returned properly. Whereas if I use the following method:

```
@PUT
@Path("/userdebug2/{userId}")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public String updateUserDebug2(MultipartFormDataInput form) 
{
    try {
        return form.getFormDataMap().get("name").get(0).getBodyAsString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "error";
}
```

I've used charlesproxy to send the same request two both urls. Here is one of them. The other one differs only by the url.

```
PUT /api/v1/userdebug1/A4BE364C-15F8-59B0-87C3-DCA0A123644A HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-5C999EAA-3828-4919-98B7-19D4FD738814
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: close
Content-Length: 205

--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-5C999EAA-3828-4919-98B7-19D4FD738814
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

ü
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-5C999EAA-3828-4919-98B7-19D4FD738814--
```

Response 1 (using the pojo form):

```
�
```

Response 2 (using MultipartFormDataInput):

```
ü
```

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Thank you in advance awesome stackoverflow community. You've already been a great help. Even if this is the first time I've asked a question.

Comment: I've upgraded to 2.3.5.Final and its fixed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same issue. 
I have stepped through the resteasy code and found that the issue appears in `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.readString(InputStream, MediaType)`.

```
public static String readString(InputStream in, MediaType mediaType) throws IOException
{
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  ByteArrayOutputStream builder = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  int wasRead = 0;
  do
  {
     wasRead = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
     if (wasRead > 0)
     {
        builder.write(buffer, 0, wasRead);
     }
  }
  while (wasRead > -1);
  byte[] bytes = builder.toByteArray();

  String charset = mediaType.getParameters().get("charset");
  if (charset != null) return new String(bytes, charset);
  else return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
}
```

The `in` input stream is a `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$ReaderBackedInputStream` (which I dont seem to have the source code for) that contains an `InputStreamReader` reading from a `ByteArrayInputStream` containing the correct UTF-8 bytes. However, when it is read it returns the wrong data. My `"nér"` `[110, -61, -87, 114]` (which is present in the buffer backing `in`) becomes `[110, -23, 114]`. This is then passed to `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` which is wrong.

I hope this helps someone, I am not getting any further, except by using the information I found in the question above, to hack around the issue by using `form.getFormDataMap().get("name").get(0).getBodyAsString()`. Thank you for that.